# How can I convert a MongoEngine Document object to BSON?

Tags: api, mongoengine, bson

The Document class in MongoEngine does not seem to have a "to_bson" function:

```
from mongoengine import *

class MyDoc(Document):
    foo = StringField()
    bar = IntField()

doc = MyDoc.objects.create(foo=u"Hello World")

print "Document BSON length is:", len(doc.to_bson())  # fails : no "to_bson"
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doc.to_mongo()` to get dict and `pymongo.bson.BSON.from_dict` (http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/bson.html to get bson. MongoEngine is wrapper for pymongo.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the above answer. Please Note that BSON.from_dict() is now deprecated.

"DEPRECATED - from_dict has been renamed to encode.

Changed in version 1.9: Deprecated in favor of encode()"

Quote from http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10/api/bson/index.html